# What is the linux version that best fits my system to install?

Tags: installation, system, versions, info

I would like to ask if you can tell me , what is the linux version that best fits my system to install ?!

Intel Pentium 4
CPU 3.40GHz
1 GB RAM
Nvidia 6600

Pending your reply ,
Thank you very much !

Comment: Assuming you are looking for an official Ubuntu version see [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/107450).  If you are considering something other than Ubuntu then this question is off topic here. You can ask on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or perhaps on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'linux version', I assume you mean 'Linux distribution'.

You have fairly low specs, so I would recommend, (as you are on ask *ubuntu*) [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/).